# Scroll inside div onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

The `.sticky` block contains a lot of data and scrolls. If I press in I want to move my scroll by 10px on every click, but it doesn't work.

How to can I scroll by 10px after clicking on `<i>`? The `ScrollBy` function works only with the `window`, but I need the same for a `div`, is it possible?

```
<div class="sticky">
    <!-- ... -->
    <i onclick="$('.sticky').scrollTop += 10" class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
    <i onclick="$('.sticky').scrollTop -= 10" class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

```css
.sticky {
    top: 130px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in jQuery `scrollTop()` is a method, so you need to call it and provide the new position to scroll to. Secondly, you need to set a `height` on `.sticky` so that it has an extent set to allow the overflow to occur. Lastly, you need to put the up/down labels outside of the `.sticky` element, otherwise they will scroll out of view.

It's also far better practice to use unobtrusive event handlers instead of inline ones. Try this:

```js
var $sticky = $('.sticky');

$('.scroll').on('click', function() {
  $sticky.scrollTop($sticky.scrollTop() + $(this).data('inc'));
});
```

```css
.sticky {
  top: 130 px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 150px;
}
.scroll {
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<i class="scroll fa fa-angle-up" data-inc="-10">Up</i>
<i class="scroll fa fa-angle-down" data-inc="10">Down</i>
<div class="sticky">
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let objDiv = document.querySelector(".sticky");

let up = document.getElementById('up');
up.addEventListener('click',function () {
    objDiv.scrollTop -= 10;
});

let down = document.getElementById('down');
down.addEventListener('click',function () {
    objDiv.scrollTop += 10;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8af1e7pr/

Answer (score 0):

`scrollTop` does not work when modifying a jQuery selection object's property; it works when used on a DOM object. You can get it using `[0]` on jQuery selection. Beware that it will only work on the first item selected if your jQuery selection returns more than one DOM object.

**NOTE**: Rory McCrossan's answer is perfectly valid too, the important point is to distinguish between jQuery's selection (which is a Javascript object that has jQuery's functions such as `scrollTop()`) and the DOM objects (you can get them with vanilla JS `querySelector`, and are contained in jQuery's selection) on which if you modify some properties like `scrollTop`, you'll see immediately the change.

```js
function goUp(){
    $('.sticky')[0].scrollTop += 10;
}

function goDown(){
    $('.sticky')[0].scrollTop -= 10;
}
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 90%;
}

.sticky {
    height: 90%;
    top: 130px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sticky">
    <!-- ... -->
    <i onclick="goUp()" class="fa fa-angle-up">test up</i><br>
    <i onclick="goDown()" class="fa fa-angle-down">test down</i><br>
    <i onclick="goUp()" class="fa fa-angle-up">test up</i><br>
    <i onclick="goDown()" class="fa fa-angle-down">test down</i><br>
    <i onclick="goUp()" class="fa fa-angle-up">test up</i><br>
    <i onclick="goDown()" class="fa fa-angle-down">test down</i><br>
    <i onclick="goUp()" class="fa fa-angle-up">test up</i><br>
    <i onclick="goDown()" class="fa fa-angle-down">test down</i><br>
    <i onclick="goUp()" class="fa fa-angle-up">test up</i><br>
    <i onclick="goDown()" class="fa fa-angle-down">test down</i><br>
    <i onclick="goUp()" class="fa fa-angle-up">test up</i><br>
    <i onclick="goDown()" class="fa fa-angle-down">test down</i><br>
    <i onclick="goUp()" class="fa fa-angle-up">test up</i><br>
    <i onclick="goDown()" class="fa fa-angle-down">test down</i><br>
    <i onclick="goUp()" class="fa fa-angle-up">test up</i><br>
    <i onclick="goDown()" class="fa fa-angle-down">test down</i><br>
    <i onclick="goUp()" class="fa fa-angle-up">test up</i><br>
    <i onclick="goDown()" class="fa fa-angle-down">test down</i><br>
    <i onclick="goUp()" class="fa fa-angle-up">test up</i><br>
    <i onclick="goDown()" class="fa fa-angle-down">test down</i><br>
    <i onclick="goUp()" class="fa fa-angle-up">test up</i><br>
    <i onclick="goDown()" class="fa fa-angle-down">test down</i><br>
    <i onclick="goUp()" class="fa fa-angle-up">test up</i><br>
    <i onclick="goDown()" class="fa fa-angle-down">test down</i><br>
    <i onclick="goUp()" class="fa fa-angle-up">test up</i><br>
    <i onclick="goDown()" class="fa fa-angle-down">test down</i><br>
    <i onclick="goUp()" class="fa fa-angle-up">test up</i><br>
    <i onclick="goDown()" class="fa fa-angle-down">test down</i><br>
    <i onclick="goUp()" class="fa fa-angle-up">test up</i><br>
    <i onclick="goDown()" class="fa fa-angle-down">test down</i><br>
    <i onclick="goUp()" class="fa fa-angle-up">test up</i><br>
    <i onclick="goDown()" class="fa fa-angle-down">test down</i><br>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```